# how to use Lastlogindata test code

Tags: apex, batch

Last Login data is readonly, so the field cannot be changed. So how can I write test code for that field?

I have a batch code that excutes and processes the lastlogindate from a certain period of time ago through batch. So how should I write a test code?

Comment: There are many ways, but in order to answer it would be nice to start with your specific implementation. Could you please add the relevant code sections to your question?